# Can a bacterium infect another bacterium?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology

I researched about it by searching on Google and reading some bacteriological articles, but I did not get any answer. I also asked some of my teachers, and they were also a bit confused. Some said that it is possible and others said not. So the question remains:

***Can a bacterium infect another bacterium? If so, how?***

Comment: Not exactly what you asked but the YouTube channel Journey to the Microcosmos may be interesting along those lines, a recent video "Our Paramecia Are Infected" discusses some of this and has very pretty microscope video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foKz81ElCjM

Answer (score 37, accepted):

*[Bdellovibrio bacteriovorus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bdellovibrio)* (BV) “infects” other bacteria:

> Similar to a virus, BV attacks bacteria such as *Escherichia coli* (*E. coli*) by attaching to and entering its prey, growing and replicating within the cell, and then suddenly bursting out, releasing its progeny into the surrounding environment. — [How bacteria hunt other bacteria](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2017/03/170328145255.htm)

Answer (score 10):

Note that a lot of the answer to this question hinges on what you mean by "infect". Bdellovibrios (as Laurel has already established that this **does** happen) do something that does look a lot like infecting eukaryotic cells- but it is still spoken of as "hunting". Why? I am not sure.

There are lots of different ways that bacteria can have negative interactions with each other- though they often resemble "hunting" or "warfare" more than "infection".

Getting a bit more into the "how" of the question, a common mechanism for inter-bacterial negative interaction is the [Type VI secretion system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_VI_secretion_system). This apparatus is often spoken of as a "weapon" that bacteria can use to kill each other, by adhering to the other cell and shooting toxins in through its membrane. [They can use this to great ecological effect.](https://www.pnas.org/content/115/36/8855)

The type VI secretion system is also used in some contexts for [infecting non-bacterial hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_VI_secretion_system#Anti-eukaryotic), so by that logic you could argue that it resembles infection.

**Update:** for a short discussion of inter-bacterial killing (including Bdellovibrio + secretion systems) in the context of biotechnological applications, see [here](https://sfamjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/1758-2229.12518).